# Adding a record to more than one case

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-field, case, required-field

I have written a visualforce page that displays a notes field, a date field, and 4 case fields. I am trying to submit the notes to each of the cases but it is only submitting it to one case. Additionally, I have tried to find a way to insert a button that adds a case field because 4 will not always be required. I can't mark them as not required because they are Master-Detail fields which are required by default. This is the code I have so far.

--------------VISUALFORCE PAGE---------------

```
<apex:page standardController="Case_Note__c" recordSetVar="MassAddCaseNotes" tabStyle="Case_Note__c" extensions="MassAddCaseNotes">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Mass Add Case Notes" />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Case Notes" >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSave" immediate="false" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveandclose}" value="Save and Close" status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSaveClose" immediate="false" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:actionStatus layout="block" startText="Saving notes. . . " stopText="" id="retrieveSaveStatus" startStyle="color:green; font-style:italic" stopStyle="color:black;"/>
            <apex:pageMessages showDetail="false" />
            <br/>
            <apex:outputText value="Enter Notes to submit to cases then select cases the notes will be submitted to." style="font-style:italic" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter Your Notes: " columns="1">
                <apex:outputLabel for="CaseNote"></apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField style="width:300px;height:100px" value="{!Case_Notes.Note__c}" id="CaseNote"  />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Date: " columns="1">
                <apex:outputLabel for="Date"></apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case_Notes.Date__c}" id="Date" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Case: " columns="1">
                <apex:outputLabel for="case"></apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case_Notes.Case__c}" id="case" />
                <apex:outputLabel for="case"></apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case_Notes.Case__c}" id="case1" />
                <apex:outputLabel for="case"></apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case_Notes.Case__c}" id="case2" />
                <apex:outputLabel for="case"></apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case_Notes.Case__c}" id="case3" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

--------------APEX CLASS -----------------------

```
public class MassAddCaseNotes {

    public Case_Note__c Case_Notes {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MassAddCaseNotes(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        Case_Notes = new Case_Note__c();
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        Case_Note__c note = new Case_Note__c(
        Note__c = Case_Notes.Note__c, Date__c = Case_Notes.Date__c, Case__c = Case_Notes.Case__c);

        insert note;

        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/');
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;

    }

    public PageReference saveandclose() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

[image: This is what the page looks like]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have 4 separate fields for the Visualforce to populate with the Case ID values. You could do this by having 4 `Case_Note__c` objects in your controller. Or you could create a separate SObject that has a lookup reference to Case (so that is not a required field) and use 4 of those. Or have 4 lookup fields on that object.

Then in your `saveandclose` you can validate the user's inputs (e.g. make sure that at least one Case is chosen and that some note text has been entered) and then transfer the data as required between the objects and insert the list of objects.

None of the above requires you to make use of the underlying StandardSetController.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship in your context is 1 Case -> n Case Notes. So, you should create a Case note for every Case.

If you want to do it dynamically, I would suggest you to check this [blog post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/managing-list-of-new-records-in.html) by Bob Buzzard.

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page standardController="Case_Note__c" recordSetVar="MassAddCaseNotes" tabStyle="Case_Note__c" extensions="MassAddCaseNotes">

<apex:sectionHeader title="Mass Add Case Notes" />      
<apex:form > 

<apex:pageBlock title="Case Notes" >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSave" immediate="false" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveandclose}" value="Save and Close" status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSaveClose" immediate="false" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>                                        
    <apex:actionStatus layout="block" startText="Saving notes. . . " stopText="" id="retrieveSaveStatus" startStyle="color:green; font-style:italic" stopStyle="color:black;"/>

    <apex:pageMessages showDetail="false" />
    <br/> 
    <apex:outputText value="Enter Notes to submit to cases then select cases the notes will be submitted to." style="font-style:italic" /><br/>             
    <br/>



<apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter Your Notes: " columns="1">
    <apex:outputLabel for="CaseNote"> </apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:inputField style="width:300px;height:100px" value="{!Case_Notes.Note__c}" id="CaseNote"  />
</apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Date: " columns="1">
    <apex:outputLabel for="Date"> </apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:inputField value="{!Case_Notes.Date__c}" id="Date" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Case: " columns="1">
    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!lstNotes}" var="c">                       
    <apex:column headerValue="Case">
        <apex:inputField value="{!c.cNote.Case__c}" id="case" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Action">
        <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!addCases}" rendered="{!IF(c.index == lstNotes.size-1,true,false)}"/>
    </apex:column>                                 
    </apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
       public class MassAddCaseNotes {
public class NoteWrapper{
    public integer index{get; set;}
    public Case_Note__c cNote{get; set;}
    public NoteWrapper(integer i, Case_Note__c cn){
        index = i;
        cNote = cn;
    }
}

public List<NoteWrapper> lstNotes{get; set;}
public Case_Note__c Case_Notes {get; set;}
public MassAddCaseNotes (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) 
{
    lstNotes.add(new NoteWrapper(lstNotes.size(),new Case_Note__c());
    Case_Notes = new Case_Note__c(); 
}
public void addCases(){
    lstNotes.add(new NoteWrapper(lstNotes.size(),new Case_Note__c()));
}

public PageReference save() 
{
    List<Case_Note__c> lstNotesToInsert = new List<Case_Note__c>();
    for(NoteWrapper nw: lstNotes){
        nw.cNote.Note__c= Case_Notes.Note__c;
        nw.cNote.Date__c= Case_Notes.Date__c;
        lstNotesToInsert.add(nw.cNote); 
    }
    insert lstNotesToInsert;         

    return null;
}

public PageReference saveandclose() 
{
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: This code looks great and makes sense, but it is giving this error             `"Error: Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!c.Case__c}'. <apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable."`

Comment: Jusrt changed a line in page code. Please try.

Comment: There are no errors on the page but when I try to go to that page it gives me this `Attempt to de-reference a null object `

Comment: I have found that it has something to do with this line `lstNotes.add(new NoteWrapper(lstNotes.size(),new Case_Note__c()));`       When I remove it, the page loads fine (with the exception of the case field not working again.)

Comment: Also, The button that is supposed to add another field does not show up on the page. The label does, but the button its self does not.  I suspect that the line of code here: `lstNotes.add(new NoteWrapper(lstNotes.size(),new Case_Note__c()));` is the culprit for both issues.